# Making commands case insensitive [Discord bot] in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord

I've seen a lot of people asking the same thing on Stack Overflow but I didn't see any of the cases in which people use the same type of code as me, like for instance I cannot use .toLowerCase().

```
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '+') {
    var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
    var cmd = args[0];


    args = args.splice(1);
    switch(cmd) {
        // Help command
        case 'HELP':
            bot.sendMessage({
                to: channelID,
                message: commandList
            });
        break;
```

Comment: I've added it to the code but it says "Cannot read property 'toLowercase' of undefined"

Comment: Added it where, exactly?

Comment: Just guessing, but you probably need to `switch(cmd.toUpperCase())`, instead of using `toLowerCase` seeing that then you compare to an all-uppercase command.

Comment: after "case" but I dont think that will be right

Comment: Try debuggin it. Try ```console.log(var)```. It will probably return undefined so the problem isn't really the ```.toLowercase()``` function

Comment: @Xattics no, that wouldn't be correct. See my previous comment about uppercasing `args` in the `switch` instead.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention that when i add .toLowerCase() that i get an error saying Unexpected token '.'

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks, this worked, im sorry for my amateurism, i just started doing this

Comment: Don't worry. In the future just remember to put all the info in the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting `toUpperCase()` here

```
var cmd = args[0].toUpperCase();
```

or here:

```
switch(cmd.toUpperCase()) {
```

And if youre getting an error saying `toUpperCase` cant be put on undefined, then your code is broken somewhere here:

```
var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
var cmd = args[0];
```

so try and see if your `message` is actually what you think it is.